# svg: why does y="0" start outside the viewport instead of in the top edge for text?

Tags: svg

This is the only thing preventing me from understanding how the coordination system works...

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="600" height="400" x="0" y="0">  
    <text x="0" y="0">  
        <tspan>&#x2709;</tspan>
    </text>  
</svg>
```

If the y-axis points down why does `y="0"` start from the outside of the viewport? Shouldn't it start right at the top edge? It blows my logic away...

The x-axis points to the right and it starts right in the left edge of the viewport, now this is logic and normal behavior.

Why does the y-axis behave like this? Or why make one start from the outside and the other not? What is the logic behind this? Unless I'm misunderstanding how it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all in the [SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewportSpace)

> the initial coordinate system has the origin at the top/left with the x-axis pointing to the right and the y-axis pointing down

The origin for text is basically the [bottom left corner of the glyph for left-to-right text](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TextLayoutIntroduction).

> For most uses of Latin text (i.e., writing-mode:lr, text-anchor:start and alignment-baseline:baseline) the alignment-point in the glyph will be the intersection of left edge of the glyph cell (or some other glyph-specific x-axis coordinate indicating a left-side origin point) with the Latin baseline of the glyph.

Comment: Maybe my understanding is wrong or I'm just blind, but where does it say that the y-axis starts outside the top edge/side? Please, quote the exact part. And what does "bottom left corner" have to do with this? This is about the top. Sorry if I'm just not seeing it...

Comment: I did quote the exact parts. The quoted text is copied and pasted from the SVG specification. Links to those parts of the specification are included in my answer.

Comment: So why doesnt it say anything about it?

Comment: If the y origin 0 is at the top of the canvas and the origin of a glyph is at the bottom of the glyph, where do you think the majority of the glyph will be displayed if the glyph's position is on the origin?

Comment: The canvas is the svg viewport and the glyph is the text, right? Hmm could you please upload a graphic example? That would be appreciated! I'm not very familiarized yet with the terminology.

Comment: text consists of glyphs (basically letters). The svg viewport and canvas are kind of interchangable terms.

Comment: Oh right I get it now... I just got that "origin of a glyph is at the bottom of the glyph", right... So the glyph will always be outside if the y-axis is 0. I was kinda slow in that one :P

Answer (score 0):

default  baseline is in text downside, can use  attr dominant-baseline change baseline, here is [mdn example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dominant-baseline#example)

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M20,20 L180,20 M20,50 L180,50 M20,80 L180,80" stroke="grey" />

    <text dominant-baseline="auto" x="30" y="20">Auto</text>
    <text dominant-baseline="middle" x="30" y="50">Middle</text>
    <text dominant-baseline="hanging" x="30" y="80">Hanging</text>
</svg>
```